# How can I get the previous activated widget in PyQt?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I have a button and two tablewidgets.Pressing the button does two different things depending on which one of the tablewidgets was activated before the push of the button.How can I get the right widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could for example use the [focusInEvent](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qwidget.html#focusInEvent) to store the activated widget and return it when pressing the button, something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyTableWidget(QtGui.QTableWidget):
    focusIn = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QObject)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyTableWidget, self).__init__(parent)

    def focusInEvent(self, event):
        self.focusIn.emit(self)

        return super(MyTableWidget, self).focusInEvent(event)

class MyWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)      

        self.lastFocusedTableWidget = None

        self.tableWidgetFirst  = MyTableWidget(self)
        self.tableWidgetFirst.setObjectName("tableWidgetFirst")
        self.tableWidgetFirst.focusIn.connect(self.on_tableWidget_focusIn)

        self.tableWidgetSecond = MyTableWidget(self)
        self.tableWidgetSecond.setObjectName("tableWidgetSecond")
        self.tableWidgetSecond.focusIn.connect(self.on_tableWidget_focusIn)

        self.pushButtonLastFocused = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButtonLastFocused.setText("Print the last focused QTableWidget!")
        self.pushButtonLastFocused.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButtonLastFocused_clicked)

        self.layoutVertical = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.tableWidgetFirst)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.tableWidgetSecond)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.pushButtonLastFocused)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QObject)
    def on_tableWidget_focusIn(self, obj):
        self.lastFocusedTableWidget = obj

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButtonLastFocused_clicked(self):
        print self.lastFocusedTableWidget.objectName()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')

    main = MyWindow()
    main.resize(333, 111)
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Can you explain when the focusIn signal is transmitted?