# How can I pass a widget as an argument in a function in Pyqt?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I have a function that moves up the selected item in two tables that I have.Until now I am using the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17376085/how-can-i-get-the-previous-activated-widget-in-pyqt) to get the appropriate widget and do the following:

```
 def move_up(self):    
    focused_table = self.lastFocusedTableWidget.objectName()
    if focused_table == 'tableWidget_3':                
        row = self.tableWidget_3.currentRow()
        column = self.tableWidget_3.currentColumn()
        if row > 0:
            self.tableWidget_3.insertRow(row-1)
            for i in range(self.tableWidget_3.columnCount()):
               self.tableWidget_3.setItem(row-1,i,self.tableWidget_3.takeItem(row+1,i))
               self.tableWidget_3.setCurrentCell(row-1,column)
            self.tableWidget_3.removeRow(row+1)  

    elif focused_table == 'tableWidget_4':
        row = self.tableWidget_4.currentRow()
        column = self.tableWidget_4.currentColumn()
        if row > 0:
            self.tableWidget_4.insertRow(row-1)
            for i in range(self.tableWidget_4.columnCount()):
               self.tableWidget_4.setItem(row-1,i,self.tableWidget_4.takeItem(row+1,i))
               self.tableWidget_4.setCurrentCell(row-1,column)
            self.tableWidget_4.removeRow(row+1)
```

How can I pass the appropriate widget and get rid of the if statements?

Comment: Have you tried just passing it in as an argument to the function? I can't see why that wouldn't work.

Comment: Can you give a simple example ?

Comment: It's like a normal argument: `def your_func(widget_arg, ...): # Use widget_arg here` and then you call it by `your_func(widget_instance, ...)`. This should work.